# How to assign day of year values starting from an arbitary date and take care of missing values?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have an R dataframe `df_demand` with a date column `(depdate)` and a dependent variable column `bookings`. The duration is 365 days starting from 2017-11-02 and ending at 2018-11-01, sorted in ascending order.

```
We have booking data for only 279 days in the year.

dplyr::arrange(df_demand, depdate)

           depdate bookings
    1   2017-11-02       43
    2   2017-11-03       27
    3   2017-11-05       27
    4   2017-11-06       22
    5   2017-11-07       39
    6   2017-11-08       48
    .
    .

   279  2018-11-01       60
```

I want to introduce another column day_of_year in the following way:

```
    depdate       day_of_year     bookings
1    2017-11-02        1              43
2    2017-11-03        2              27
3    2017-11-04        3              NA
4    2017-11-05        4              27
    .
    .
    .
365  2018-11-01      365              60
```

I am trying to find the best possible way to do this.

In Python, I could use something like :

```
df_demand['day_of_year'] = df_demand['depdate'].sub(df_demand['depdate'].iat[0]).dt.days + 1
```

I wanted to know about an `R equivalent` of the same.

When I run

```
typeof(df_demand_2$depdate)
```

the output is

```
"double"
```

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: The cause of your data type errors is that you did not change the name of the data frame everywhere. Change it to `min(df_demand_2$depdate)` etc. and it should work.

Comment: Yes I have realized that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a row for every date using the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package.

First, I'm creating a data frame with some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  depdate = as.Date(c('2017-11-02', '2017-11-03', '2017-11-05')),
  bookings = c(43, 27, 27)
)
```

Next, I'm performing two operations. First, using `tidyr::complete`, I'm specifying all the dates I want in my analysis. I can do that using `seq.Date`, creating a sequence from the first to the last day.

Once that is done, the `day_of_year` column is simply equal to the row number.

```
df_complete <- tidyr::complete(df,
  depdate = seq.Date(from = min(df$depdate), to = max(df$depdate), by = 1)
)

df_complete$day_of_year <- 1:nrow(df_complete)

> df_complete
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   depdate    bookings day_of_year
#>   <date>        <dbl>       <int>
#> 1 2017-11-02       43           1
#> 2 2017-11-03       27           2
#> 3 2017-11-04       NA           3
#> 4 2017-11-05       27           4
```

An equivalent solution with the pipe operator from `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  complete(depdate = seq.Date(from = min(df$depdate), to = max(df$depdate), by = 1)) %>%
  mutate(days_of_year = row_number())
```

Comment: Nice answer. Why not keep it all in one pipeline? , i.e. `df %>% complete(depdate = seq.Date(from = min(df$depdate), to = max(df$depdate), by = 1)) %>% mutate(days_of_year = row_number())`

Comment: That was my original answer, but as I'm not sure how familiar the OP is with pipelines, I decided to remove the dependency. In my opinion, pipelines are mostly valuable when there are many operations, and unnecessary in this simple case.

Comment: It makes it look a bit cumbersome IMO. Pipelines are much more readable and much more likely to help new users

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I run the code, I get an error: 'min' is not meaningful for factors. What could be the reason for this? Sorry, I am not very much familiar with R.

Comment: @Sotos I agree with you on the readability, and I'm happy that both options are now here so OP can choose which he/she prefers.

Comment: Yup. You should also add it in your answer. Comments get deleted sometimes :)

Comment: @rahul the problem is probably that your `depdate` column is not actually in `Date` format. You can change the data type of that column using base functions like `as.Date`, or you can try the `lubridate` package for some more advanced options. Note that I do the data type conversion in my creation of the sample data frame.

Comment: thanks. I had already used something like this: df_demand_2$depdate <- lubridate::dmy(df_demand_2$depdate)

Comment: Did that solve the problem for you? If not, can you add the output of `str(df_demand_2)` to your original question?

Comment: @A. Stam  added some more details in the question for your reference